# Using spread operator with event listeners in VueJS 2 and JSX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is a simple version for my problem:

```
render (h) {
  let events = {onClick: handleClick}
  return (<div {...events}></div>)
}
```

`onClick`event was not add to the `div` element, and spread operator works well with `class` and `style` attribute but not any of the event listener bindings (starts with `on` or `nativeOn`). Can somebody explain why and offer me a solution that I can bind arbitrary amount of event on a element?

Comment: Your return statement isn't valid javascript.

Comment: @thanksd It's JSX: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
render (h) {
  const hi = function () {
    console.log('hello')
  }
  return (
    <div { ...{ on: {click: hi} } } > click me! </div>
  )
}
```

Here the link to babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx [issues](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/70)

Comment: Thanks! I do not know that the reason why not put it into document, or they thought that we have already familiar with JSX?

Comment: @zl2003cn `{ ...{ on: {click: hi} } }` just mean that you you need to define event under `on` object. Yes this part need to be mentioned in documentation. It is not obvious